# UITableViewController load numberOfRowsInSection after reading database

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How do I make UITableViewController load numberOfRowsInSection after reading database?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {             
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("key").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
         for child in snapshot.children{
             let data = child as! DataSnapshot
             let key = story.key
             self.KeyArray.append(key)
          }
    })
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.storyKeyArray.count // this returns 0, expectedly...
}
```

similarly, i only want load "cellForRowAt" function after reading the database too.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 0, `cellForRowAt` will not be called.

After reading the database, call `reloadData()` on the table view. Be sure to do it on the main thread.

```
ref.child("key").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
      for child in snapshot.children{
         // ... populate storyKeyArray somehow ...
      }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
})
```

This causes your data source methods to be called *again*, and this time `storyKeyArray` will have a non-zero `count` and your `cellForRowAt:` will be called to supply the cells.

Answer (score 0):

After you read the data base, you have to reload the table view